# Ag-grid number filter decimal separator

Tags: ag-grid

Does the number filter (agNumberColumnFilter) in ag-grid allow choosing a decimal separator?

Currently, it seems that only a dot is allowed (e.g. “1.5”) when entering a value in the filter, even if the browser locale uses a comma as the decimal separator ( (1.5).toLocaleString() == “1,5”).

So far, I’ve only found a workaround – replacing NumberFilter.prototype.onFilterChanged to allow a comma.

Is there out-of-the box functionality for selecting the decimal separator? Since ag-grid officially supports internationalisation, support for both dot and comma is a fundamental requirement…